# Factorizing a cubic polynomial in 3 variables.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I recently saw a question in which we had to factorize a cubic polynomial in 3 variable. The method shown in the answer asked me to assume any 2 variables as constants and 1 as a variable and then follow the factor theorem. Just then a question struck my mind about the expression :--
$$(xyz-1)$$
I tried to factorise it by the above method. First I assumed $x$ as variable, then $y$ and then $z$ as variable and ended up with :--
$$(x-\frac{1}{yz})(y-\frac{1}{xz})(z-\frac{1}{yx})$$
And I had factorised it in 3 factors because the polynomial was cubic. The above 3 factors satisfy the expression through factor theorem but when we actually multiply the 3 factors we end up having some thing else. Please tell me where I went wrong. It would be a great help. $$Thank you$$

Comment: `First I assumed x as variable` The polynomial has degree $1$ in $x\,$, and factors simply as $yz(x-\frac{1}{yz})\,$. `and ended up with` You didn't post *that* part, which is where the error must be.

Comment: You forgot to consider the leading coefficient...

Comment: Oh. I realised what I did wrong. I considered variables 3 times and I should have done it once. Thats why I ended up multiplying the orignal polynomial 3 times and also dividing it with squares of the variables.